# Disable specific option from react-select isMulti reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

How should I disable specific options from react-select isMulti based on the condition provided.

```
import Select from 'react-select'
const Systems = () => {
  const [dataSystems, setdataSystems] = useState([])
  const [systemDetails, setsystemDetails] = useState({
    SYSTEMID: 1,
    ......
  })

  const getSystems = async() => {
   await axios.get('/API')
     .then(response => {
       setdataSystems(response.data)
     })
  }

const [multiSelected, setmultiSelected] = useState();
var handleMultiSelect = (e) => {
  setmultiSelected(Array.isArray(e)?e.map(x=> x.value):[]);
}

const bodyInsertDepSystem = (
  .......
  <Select
    isMulti
    options = {dataSystems.map(e => ({ label: e.SYSTEMALIAS, value: e.SYSTEMID }))}
    onChange = {handleMultiSelect} > </Select>
)


}
```

What I want to do is to remove the disable the SYSTEMID from the dropdown that has same ID as systemDetails.SYSTEMID.

Hope that you can help me with this.

What I really doing on this: During edit I want to relate one SYSTEMID to multiple SYSTEMID but I want to disable or remove that has same SYSTEMID

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select
  isMulti
  options = {dataSystems.map(e => ({
    label: e.SYSTEMALIAS,
    value: e.SYSTEMID
    isDisabled: e.SYSTEMID == systemDetails.SYSTEMID ? true: null
    }))}
  onChange = {handleMultiSelect}>
</Select>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.